# How to declare an object enum in a definitions file?

Tags: typescript

Given the following javascript file (test.js):

```
const someType = {
  val1: "myvalue",
  val2: "myothervalue"
};

function sampleFunction(param) {
  return 1;
}

function sampleFunction2(param) {
  return 2;
}

export {someType, sampleFunction, sampleFunction2};
```

And the following definitions file (test.d.ts):

```
declare module "test" {
  // basically an enum object in the module
  export type someType = {
    val1: 'myvalue',
    val2: 'myothervalue',
  }

  export function sampleFunction(param1: someType): number;
  export function sampleFUnction2(param1: someType): number;
}
```

What is the correct way to define the object enum in the definitions file?

```
import sampleFunction, someType from 'test';

console.log(sampleFunction(someType.val1)); /// someType is unavailable
```

The above doesn't work since it seems someType isn't a valid value. Importing with `{ someType }` gives a separate error that it's a type being used as a value.

https://codepen.io/Renari/project/editor/DQNjeO#0

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Comment: @DerekBrown I've tried that the issue with that is that the definitions file doesn't seem to let you export the enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types can't appear in expressions. You want to declare a constant with this type since the constant is declared and will exist at runtime:

```
declare module "test" {
  export const someType: {
    val1: 'myvalue',
    val2: 'myothervalue',
  }
  type someTypeValue = typeof someType[keyof typeof someType];
  export function sampleFunction(param1: someTypeValue): number;
  export function sampleFUnction2(param1: someTypeValue): number;
}
// usage.ts
import { sampleFunction, someType} from 'test';

console.log(sampleFunction(someType.val1));
console.log(sampleFunction('myvalue')); // will also work
```

The above sample exposes the const directly and allows you to pass in any string that is a value of `sampleType`.

You could also model this using an actual enum which will hide the string values in the const:

```
declare module "test" {
  export enum someType {
    val1 = "myvalue",
    val2 = 'myothervalue'
  }
  export function sampleFunction(param1: someType): number;
  export function sampleFUnction2(param1: someType): number;
}
// usage.ts
import { sampleFunction, someType} from 'test';

console.log(sampleFunction(someType.val1));
console.log(sampleFunction('myvalue')); // error
```

Depending on what you want to achieve either version can work

Comment: The `enum` describes an object whose values are numbers, but these are actually strings.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh fair enough :)

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh but an enum could still work I think, I updated the answer with a string enum.